# Uniqueness of the solution of $y" + py' + qy = 0$ where $p,q$ are continuous functions and $y(0)=y(1)=0$

Tags: real-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations

I'm trying to show the following result:

Let $p,q$ be two continuous functions : $[0,1]\to \mathbb R$ such as $q\leq 0$. Let's consider:
$$
(E): \quad y"+py'+qy = 0
$$

(where here $py',qy$ mean $x\mapsto p(x)y'(x)$ and $x\mapsto q(x)y(x)$).

Show that the unique solution $y$ verifying $y(0)=y(1)=0$ is the null function.

---

I don't know if there is an easier way, but I went that way:

It is easy to solve if $q<0$: without loss of generality, suppose $y\geq0$ on $[0,1]$ (we can choose the sign by $y \mapsto -y$ and rescale between 0 and the first zero of the function to be sure $y\neq0$). There is at least a local maximum $c\in (0,1)$ so $y$ verifies $y''(c)\leq 0 (\star)$ and $y'(c)=0$. For all such $c$, injecting in (E)leads to: $ y"(c) = -q(c)y(c) \geq 0$. If $y(c)=0$, by virtue of Cauchy's theorem, $y=0$. If $y(c)>0$, this inequality becomes $y''(c)>0$ which is impossible considering $(\star)$.

My problem to generalize is to find a way to deal with the case where $\exists c\in(0,1), ~~ q(c)=0$. I cannot find a way to be sure to have strict inequalities.

Comment: Does $py'$ mean a function of $y'$ or does it mean $y'$ multiplied by a function of $y$ or $x$ (or $t$ or whatever)?

Comment: It means $p(x)\times y(x)$ where $x\in [0,1]$ is the real variable

Comment: I think you intended "$p(x)\times y'(x)$" but thank you for the edit to the question